# problem installing meld on 12.04 64 bit LTS(1)

Tags: 12.04, installation

I get this error during apt-get  BUT - when I install my original disk it still doesn't like it and requests this specific disk again.  Did NOT happen (no CD request) on another meld install on another system that was loaded using same OS disk.   Why is it asking for CD?  NEVER had it do that before (on Ubuntu since 9.04).

```
mdr@mars:~$ sudo apt-get install meld --fix-missing
[sudo] password for mdr: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libbonobo2-0 libbonobo2-common libbonoboui2-0 libbonoboui2-common
  libglade2-0 libgnome2-0 libgnome2-bin libgnomecanvas2-0
  libgnomecanvas2-common libgnomeui-0 libgnomeui-common libgnomevfs2-0
  libgnomevfs2-common libgtksourceview2.0-0 libgtksourceview2.0-common
  python-glade2 python-gnome2 python-gtksourceview2 python-pyorbit
Suggested packages:
  libbonobo2-bin libgnomevfs2-bin libgnomevfs2-extra gamin fam gnome-mime-data
  python-gtk2-doc python-gnome2-doc libgtksourceview2.0-dev python-pyorbit-dbg
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libbonobo2-0 libbonobo2-common libbonoboui2-0 libbonoboui2-common
  libglade2-0 libgnome2-0 libgnome2-bin libgnomecanvas2-0
  libgnomecanvas2-common libgnomeui-0 libgnomeui-common libgnomevfs2-0
  libgnomevfs2-common libgtksourceview2.0-0 libgtksourceview2.0-common meld
  python-glade2 python-gnome2 python-gtksourceview2 python-pyorbit
0 upgraded, 20 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/2,423 kB of archives.
After this operation, 11.7 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y

Media change: please insert the disc labeled
 'Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120823.1)'
in the drive '/cdrom/' and press enter
```

Answer (score 0):

You must remove the CDROM source and install it via Internet.

- Graphical mode:

  1. Open the software center
  2. Menu "Edit" -> "Software Sources..."
  3. Tab "Other Software"
  4. Uncheck the "cdrom"
- Console mode:

  1. Remove the cdrom line: `sudo sed -i '/cdrom:/d' /etc/apt/sources.list`
  2. Resynchronize the package index files: `sudo apt-get update`

Try again.